# I'm trying to instantiate a chaincode wriiten in node.js on the hyperledger fabric but I'm getting error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2, hyperledger-chaincode

I installed the chaincode on the network but when I'm trying to instantiate,
I'm getting :

> "Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded"
>   [image: error_image-1]

Also, I tried to add TLS but then I get the following error:

> Error: error getting broadcast client: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file:
>   [image: error_image-2]

And, the orderer logs are: [image: logs]

My orderer TLS is enabled now:
[image: Orderer TLS enabled]

I'll be glad if someone can help or guide me atleast, I'm new to HyperledgerFabric.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adapt to your case:

```sh
peer chaincode instantiate -n mychannel -v 1.0 -C petshop -c '{"Args":[""]}' -o 127.0.0.1:7050 --tls --cafile /path/to/orderer/tls/ca.pem
```

Comment: $ peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile "E:/E_drive/hlf/Test/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n petshop -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com: no such host"

Comment: Is your orderer really accessible from your peer client at 127.0.0.1:7050? Check it through telnet and check your orderer logs.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "orderer" logs precisely at the time you are instantiating the chaincode (first without TLS and then with TLS). You can see that time from your command-line when you are running that command.

Update your question with that section of orderer logs.

Also, if I need to guess from your current orderer nodes, you might not have enabled TLS for the orderer container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check that once. :)

Comment: I'm getting same error when trying to invoke the already deployed chaincode. Also, this time I checked, orederer TLS is enabled. How can I disable the orderer TLS, will that solve my problem?

Comment: From the error it seems that the orderer is not able to find TLS certificate at the given mount path. Check what is present at the following path: `/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt` inside the orderer container.

Comment: There is nothing on this path but even when I specify 'fabric-samples\test-network\organizations\ordererOrganizations\example.com\orderers\orderer.example.com\tls\ca.crt', it shows the same error. How can I change path?

Comment: You need to change the mount path inside the docker-compose file for the orderer container. Locate your docker-compose file and give the source mount path to `ca.crt` relative to that location. You can see the `first-network` sample in the `fabric-samples` for identifying how to mount paths in docker container. Also, you are using WSL so you must check how to mount volumes in docker for WSL.