# Error while invoking javascript chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode basic2 has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'basic2' exists, but chaincode is not installed"**

It gives me this error whenever I try to invoke chaincode but when I try to install chaincode again it shows that chain code is successfully installed. what should be the meaning of this error?
It also does not create a docker container.
So i try to instantiated with command

**COMMAND: peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -l node -n basic2 -v 1 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P 'OR ("Org1MSP.member")'**

But then i got new error:

**Error: error getting broadcast client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded**

I check the logs of Orderer then it shows :

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is problem and how should i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the tls using the '--tls' flag. Also, you can refer to this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064371/im-trying-to-instantiate-a-chaincode-wriiten-in-node-js-on-the-hyperledger-fabr)

Make sure you're following the steps properly. Also, if you're sure about the steps, sometimes it works if you retry without making any changes, just repeat the step where you're facing the error without making any changes, it should work on the 3rd try atmost if everything goes well.

Comment: yes, it did work but i got new Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg Channel 'mychannel' has been migrated to the new lifecycle, LSCC is now read-only